# PlotRange -> Automatic/All/Full does not adjust the z-axis

Tags: plotting

I have this code

```
 ParametricPlot3D[{(Sin[t]/30), (Cos[t]/30), 0}, {t, 0, (2 π)}, 
   PlotRange -> Automatic]
```

the output (below) shows that the options `Automatic` is not adjusting the z axis to better visualize the circle. How can I solve this? The same thing happens when I put `PlotRange -> All` or `PlotRange -> Full`. I am doing a list with thousands of tinny plots around the origin, so manual setting the `PlotRange` is not an option to me.

[image]

Comment: You should look at  the `BoxRatios` option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this closer to what you want?

```
ParametricPlot3D[{(Sin[t]/30), (Cos[t]/30), 0}, {t, 0, (2 π)}, 
  PlotRange -> {Automatic, Automatic, {-.05, .05}},
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 0.1}]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: `BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 0.1}` alone would work too, you don't really need to set `PlotRange`, right?

Comment: Thank you Blackow! BoxRatios solve the problem.

Comment: @BlacKow. The reason for adding the `PlotRange` option is to get readable labels on the z-axis.